# INSERT WITH A CONDITION IN POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql

If AD_EntityType =1000000 then, i dont want to execute below  query . please correct it

```
INSERT INTO AD_EntityType (AD_Client_ID,AD_EntityType_ID,AD_Org_ID,Created,CreatedBy,Description,EntityType,IsActive,Name,Processing,Updated,UpdatedBy) 
 VALUES (0,1000000,0,TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-05 15:05:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),100,'Human Resource Management System','H','Y','HR','N',
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-05 enter code here15:05:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),100)
```

Comment: did you write the query in postgresql function or front end

Comment: Are you attempting to write code that does an "insert if not exists" operation? i.e. "Create EntityType with id=1000000 only if it does not already exist" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO AD_EntityType (AD_Client_ID,AD_EntityType_ID,AD_Org_ID,Created,CreatedBy,Description,EntityType,IsActive,Name,Processing,Updated,UpdatedBy) 
SELECT 0,1000000,0,TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-05 15:05:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),100,'Human Resource Management System','H','Y','HR','N',TO_TIMESTAMP('2013-07-05 enter code here15:05:13','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),100
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM AD_EntityType WHERE AD_EntityType_ID = 1000000)
```

The data is not inserted in case you have the `AD_EntityType_ID = 1000000` value in your table.

Comment: There will be no errors with this query even if the value exists